# How to keep font preferences in TexWorks 4

Tags: texworks

The default font is too small on my screen at the resolution I have it, so I like to reset the font to size 12, but it appears I have to do this everytime I launch the program.  How do I make it remember my preferences?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to `Edit`->`Preferences`->`Editor`, make the changes, click `OK`, close the editor and reopen. The preferences will be saved.

The problem arises here because if you use `Format`->`Font` instead to configure, the settings only apply to that session.