# TeXworks source window

Tags: texworks

Is there a way to increase the font size in the source window of TeXworks? I guess I'm showing my age, but for me it is almost unusable. It's kind of annoying having to put my face so close to the screen to get any work done.

Comment: This question is a subset of [How to keep font preferences in TexWorks 4 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/how-to-keep-font-preferences-in-texworks-4) .

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit --> Preferences, look under the Editor tab. Here you can change font and font size. Restart TeXworks to see the effects.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this way to increase the size of the editor

Menu Format- Font - Size

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add an screenshot of that menu and opend menu point to your answer?

Comment: Sure, here you have [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VQhDS1d6IafvONUmPdAr_AtvB70NFGUb)

Comment: Please add the screenshot to your answer, a link can vanish by time, the added image in the answer not ...

Comment: Looks like this method isn't persistent -- see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571306/change-default-font-size-in-miktex , [How to keep font preferences in TexWorks 4 - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21072/how-to-keep-font-preferences-in-texworks-4)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about the **same question**, **but for TexMaker (windows)**, and I did not find the "edit --> preference" as suggested by Torbjørn T.
I have found this solution:
Options => Configure TeXmaker, select "Editor" and then "editor font size"
(I hope this might be useful for those like me who faced the same problem as Byron Schmuland but use a different tex compiler)

Comment: This does not answer the question and is better-suited as a comment.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I cannot comment either answers or questions that are not mine, because of my low reputation on this Stackexchange chapter

Comment: Yet, I thought what I added could help other users who are seeking for the answer to the question, but applied to other compilers and stumble on this page.

Comment: This is a very common hurdle: Low reputation but want to contribute. I've flagged this post to be converted to a comment by a moderator. Spend some time on the site and you'll gain the necessary reputation to share your wealth of knowledge.

Comment: It is an answer, just to the wrong question ([Larger font in TeXmaker - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467493/larger-font-in-texmaker)). So just delete this one.