# Is there a way to change the size of the text in my latex script?

Tags: editors

So this is likely a very elementary question, but I can't seem to find out how to make the text in my latex *script* bigger, not the actual document. Is that possible? If so, how can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: do you mean the view in the editor, rather than the final typeset document? That is a feature of the editor you use, but you have not said which that is.

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: miktex is a tex distribution you can still use any text editor to write the tex source. I don't use miktex but I believe it has an option to install texworks is that the editor you are using? I don't use texworks but if that is the editor you are using, the question is answered here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118513/texworks-source-window