# Change Default Font Size in MikTeX?

Tags: fonts, miktex, fontsize, editors, texworks

I downloaded MiKTeX to my computer. I know how to change the font size in a document, and I understand that different document classes have a different default font size. My question is instead about how to change the default font size in the tex editor. It defaults to 8 and I have to manually make it bigger (Format -> Font... -> Font Size) every time I open a new tex file. Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I am using TeXworks.

Comment: You should mentioned which editor you use.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for pointing this out, just updated in the question.

Comment: In the menue, go to `edit`--> `preferences`--> `editor`. There you can change the font size.

Comment: See also the following possible duplicate question: [How to keep font preferences in TexWorks 4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21072/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, that took care of it! The font size box was quite small and I must have overlooked it originally.